# Trying to install wxPython Phoenix for python 3

Tags: python, wxpython

When I tried to install wx Phoenix via pip with this command

```
pip3 install --upgrade --trusted-host wxpython.org --pre -f http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/ wxPython_Phoenix
```

Well, after a long time trying to build it I get this error:

```
Command "/usr/local/bin/python3.4 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;
__file__='/tmp/pip-build-q1ih5z3f/wxPython-Phoenix/setup.py';
exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" 
install --record /tmp/pip-wygy2a7y-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1
in /tmp/pip-build-q1ih5z3f/wxPython-Phoenix/
```

Anyone have the same problem? How I can fix this?

Comment: I'd suggest to download a binary wheel for your platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are on a Unix plattform. In that case the command as entered by you will not find any wheel, download the source package and try to compile it. See in the [README.txt](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/README.txt) what to do to get wxPython Linux wheels:

```
Wheels for Linux
----------------

Since there are various options for distro and wx port (GTK2 or GTK3) then the
files can not all be located in the same folder like we can do for the Windows
and OSX builds.  This just simply means that you'll need to drill down a
little further to find the URL to give to pip.  For example, to get the GTK3
Phoenix builds for Ubuntu 16.04 (and 16.10, LinuxMint 18, and probably others)
you can use a pip command like this:

    pip install -U --pre \
        -f https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/linux/gtk3/ubuntu-16.04 \
        wxPython_Phoenix
```